# How to make ik target overlap with its constrained bone's location

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

I know that the general practice when creating an ik rig for say a leg, you constrain lower leg bone to ik target and create a copy rotation constraint from the ik target to the foot.

Now I would like instead to have the foot bone directly constrained to ik target. To make this setup work I enabled rotation option in IK solver's constraint. But what I haven't been able to do is to make the IK target's location and the foot's (that is constrained to this target) location to overlap. This would allow me to directly rotate the foot from its pivot point instead of from its tail.

This is how the setup look right now. The foot bone's TAIL is matching the ik target location:

[image]

And this is how I would like it to look (don't mind that the foot doesn't look to be constrained), with foot bone's HEAD matching ik target location:

[image]

Is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, this is easiest to achieve, when the (first) constrained bone in the IK chain points to the target. I added a helper bone *LowerLegHelper* (which is the parent of *Foot* and *Lower Leg*) and added the **IK** constraint to it.

If you want *Foot* to be reoriented like *IK_Target*, simply add a **Copy Rotation** Constraint to it.

[image: ik chain]

Comment: Thanks, this is a viable approach. I was wondering if it is possible to achieve what I want without using helper bones, but it doesn't seem so.

Comment: Since the IK chain always ends at the tip of the constrained bone, your setup requires additional bones.

Comment: The IK system in Blender is so limited. It's a shame.